# finding the minimal polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}[\omega]$ where $\omega^2+\omega+1=0$ and let $R$ be the polynomial ring $K[x]$. Let $L$ be the field $K(x)[y]$ where $y$ satisfies $y^3=1+x^2$.

Take an element $\alpha\in L$. How can we find the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ over $K(x)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of $1$ and $K(x) \subset L$ is a cubic extension, the extension is Galois and the Galois group is obtained by replacing $y$ with $y, \omega y, \omega^2 y$ : concretely, those automorphisms are the three maps $L \to L$ sending $f(y) \mapsto f(y), f(\omega y), f(\omega^2 y)$.

Now, if you have an element $\alpha(y) \in L$, if $\alpha(y) = \alpha(\omega y)$ then $\alpha(y) \in K(x)$ : you can write $\alpha$ as a rational function of $y^3$ (there is a $\beta \in K(x)[Z]$ such that $\alpha(y) = \beta(y^3)$), and then $\alpha(y) = \beta(1+x^2) \in K(x)$, so its minimal polynomial is $Z - \beta(1+x^2)$.

If $\alpha(y) \neq \alpha( \omega y)$, then $\alpha(y) \notin K(x)$, so $\alpha(y)$ has $3$ distinct conjugates, and its minimal polynomial is $(Z - \alpha(y))(Z- \alpha(\omega y))(Z - \alpha(\omega^2 y))$. If you develop this polynomial, you will find that you can express each coefficient as a rational function of $y^3$ (just like in the previous case), which means that they are in $K(x)$ as needed.

Comment: suppose i know that coefficients of minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ lie in $K[x]$, not only in $K(x)$. Can i deduce from your answer that $\alpha$ lies in $K[x][y]$?

Comment: if $\alpha$ is in $K[x][y]$, then it is easy to see that every coefficient of its minimal polynomial is in $K[x][y^3] = K[x]$. I am not so sure about the converse though.

Comment: there is a theorem that says (applied to this case) that if $\alpha$ is integral over $K[x]$, then its minimal polynomial's coefficients are in the integral closure of $K[x]$ in $K(x)$, which is $K[x]$ itself. Hence all depends on whether $k[x][y]$ is the integral closure of $K[x]$ in $L$ or not